# How do I make Graphics2D draw a tooltip on Mouse Hover

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, graphics, graphics2d

so I have initialized each individual vertex as a JLabel and drawn the dot on the application with Graphics2D. However, I can't get a mouse listener to work with the graphic drawing for some reason. I am trying to get a tooltip to appear whenever the user has their mouse on the point (making an interractive graph).

```
package GUI;

    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.Graphics2D;
    import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
    import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

    import javax.swing.JLabel;

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public class Vertex extends JLabel {

    int x;
    int y;
    private int pointWidth;


    public Vertex(int x, int y, int pointWidth, Graphics2D g2) {

        g2.fillOval(x, y, pointWidth, pointWidth);

        //This above works

        setLocation(x, y);
        setSize(pointWidth, pointWidth);

        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener() {
            @Override //This below doesn't work, but it does print out correct coordinates
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent event) {
                //double x = event.getPoint().getX();
                //double y = event.getPoint().getY();
                System.out.println(x+pointWidth/2+"    "+y+pointWidth/2);

                //Graphics g2 = getGraphics();

                g2.setColor(new Color(0,0,0,250));
                g2.fillRect(x, y, 100, 100);

                g2.dispose();
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event) {
                //do nothing idc
            }
        });

    }

    public int getPointWidth() {
        return pointWidth;
    }

    public void setPointWidth(int pointWidth) {
        this.pointWidth = pointWidth;
    }

}
```

I am hoping to get information written on the tooltip, so if you could give me information on how to draw it with text on it? Or maybe I have to initialise the tooltip as a panel? I am not sure, I need help with that

Comment: Set the `tooltipText` for the table directly. You can also override [`JComponent#getTooltipLocation`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getToolTipLocation-java.awt.event.MouseEvent-) to change the location of the tooltip.

Comment: I just want to point out this seems like a weird implementation. Why would you use a `JLabel` to draw a single dot? Why not use a `JPanel` and draw all of them through the `paintComponent`  method?

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to know exactly what to suggest, but lets start with the fact the Swing components support tooltip text out of the box, see [How to Use Tool Tips](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tooltip.html)

This would suggest that all you really need to do is call `setToolTipText` and let the system do the rest.

However, based on the available code, I think you're abusing `JLabel`.  Personally, I'd start with a `JPanel`, it's much more flexible and does't have the same overhead and complexity that `JLabel` does.

I would then start with a concept of a `Vertex`, which just holds information about the point

```
public class Vertex {
    private Point point;

    public Vertex(Point point) {
        this.point = point;
    }

    public Point getPoint() {
        return point;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Vertex @ " + getPoint().x + "x" + getPoint().y;
    }

}
```

I'd then create some kind of "drawable" concept which can draw the `Vertex` the way you want to do (I like to decouple these things)

For me, I'd simply extend a `Ellipse2D.Double` to draw the `Vertex`, it is self drawing and has collision detection capabilities built in, very important for what you want to achieve.

```
public class VertexPoint extends Ellipse2D.Double {
    private Vertex vertex;

    public VertexPoint(Vertex vertex) {
        super(vertex.getPoint().x - 5, vertex.getPoint().y - 5, 10, 10);
        this.vertex = vertex;
    }

    public Vertex getVertex() {
        return vertex;
    }

}
```

I'd then simply override the `getToolTipText(MouseEvent)` and `paintComponent` methods, these would provide the core functionality needed to achieve (what I believe) is you core result...

```
@Override
public String getToolTipText(MouseEvent event) {
    for (VertexPoint vp : verticies) {
        if (vp.contains(event.getPoint())) {
            return vp.getVertex().toString();
        }
    }
    return null;
}

protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
    for (VertexPoint vertex : verticies) {
        g2d.fill(vertex);
    }
    g2d.dispose();
}
```

As you can see, `VertexPoint` has a cool `contains(Point)` method, which can easily be used to determine if (in this case) the mouse is over a vertex or not.

## Runnable example...

Because that's a nice bunch of out of context mumbo-jumble

[image: Tooltip hover]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class Vertex {
        private Point point;

        public Vertex(Point point) {
            this.point = point;
        }

        public Point getPoint() {
            return point;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Vertex @ " + getPoint().x + "x" + getPoint().y;
        }

    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private List<VertexPoint> verticies;

        public TestPane() {
            verticies = new ArrayList<>(25);
            Random rnd = new Random();
            for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
                int x = rnd.nextInt(200 - 10);
                int y = rnd.nextInt(200 - 10);
                add(new Vertex(new Point(x, y)));
            }
            setToolTipText("");
        }

        public void add(Vertex vertex) {
            verticies.add(new VertexPoint(vertex));
        }

        @Override
        public String getToolTipText(MouseEvent event) {
            for (VertexPoint vp : verticies) {
                if (vp.contains(event.getPoint())) {
                    return vp.getVertex().toString();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            for (VertexPoint vertex : verticies) {
                g2d.fill(vertex);
            }
            g2d.dispose();
        }

        public class VertexPoint extends Ellipse2D.Double {
            private Vertex vertex;

            public VertexPoint(Vertex vertex) {
                super(vertex.getPoint().x - 5, vertex.getPoint().y - 5, 10, 10);
                this.vertex = vertex;
            }

            public Vertex getVertex() {
                return vertex;
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Oh alright, that looks awesome, I might try with a JLabel instead of a tooltip so that it comes up instantly and feels more responsive. I thought I had to use Graphics2D so I can tie the mouseMotionListener() to the bounds of a rectangle. Which is the reason why I also made individual JLabels for each vertex. I didnt think JPanels had mouseMotionListeners so I was forced to do this per vertex. I will try your implementation and let you know how it goes.